# Integrate over 300000k rows with scipy.integrate quad is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, python-3.8

I am using the following def on a dataframe "df_append" with 366036 rows.
The df has the columns Fn and a.

```
def f(r):
    return (((3*Fn[i])/(2*math.pi*a[i]**2))*(1-((r**2)/(a[i]**2)))**(1/2))

res = []
for i in range(len(df_append)):
    res += [(1/(-a[i]-a[i]))*(quad(f, a[i], -a[i])[0])]
```

And it's incredibly slow, around 10 minutes. Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Comment: Doing anything 300M times will be slow, there's no way around it.

Comment: Use `res.append(new_value)` rather than `res += [new_value]`

Comment: Why are you looping over the length of `df_append` but then accessing `a` instead of the df?

Comment: In general you should avoid looping over dataframes, you should use pandas's built-in iteration features like `.apply()`

Comment: @Barmar, `apply` is slow too, unless it's a specialized pandas function, or 'raw' mode.

Comment: why do you write a list comprehension as a for loop

Comment: what is `a[i]` inside the function `f`, don't use `**` if you want the square, power is an expensive generic function, for sqrt, use `sqrt`, for square use `x*x`, don't lookup `a[i]` 4 times in the same expression, `-a[i]-a[i]` === `-2*a[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your function

[image]

it will draw a half ellipsis of height `3Fn[i]/2*pi*a[i]**2` and width `2*a[i]`.

So you can replace the whole integration by

[image]

```py
res = []
for i in range(len(df_append)):
    res += [(3*Fn[i])/(8*a[i]**2)]
```

This should give a significant speedup, and run in less than 1 second.

if your `Fn`  and `a` can broadcast arithmetic operations, e.g. numpy arrays, you can simply write

```py
res = (3*Fn[i])/(8*a[i]**2);
```

and it runs in less than 0.1 second.